# Having trouble with the Github commit Button in visual studio code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When I was trying to make some commit in Github repository, I am unable to click on the commit button.

[image: unable to click on the commit button]

I tried other ways like making commit through terminal and tried to push. But it wasn't working.

Comment: What does "it wasn't working" mean when you tried to make a commit through the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add stage the files only then you can commit, f you want to use CLI write `git add <filename>` or if you want to add all the changes write `git add .`
If you still want to use VSCode, just click on `+` button when hovering on file name in git sidebar and after you have added all the files you have to commit, then you can write commit message and push

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to what's suggested about staging the changes, you can commit all changes if nothing is staged: look for `git.enableSmartCommit` in the settings and check it if you're in the GUI or set it to `true` if working with `settings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: **File** -> **Preference** -> **Settings**.
Step 2: Then, search ***git.enableSmartCommit*** in settings.
Step 3: Enable the ***Git: Enable Smart Commit*** option.

[image]